# Do we have any information on what the homes of Aristotle or Plato would have looked like?

Tags: ancient-greece, philosophy, plato

I wonder because of how influential and famous they were at their time, immediately following, and effectively forever after that (with the exception of Aristotle's slight dark age of having his materials burned), if there were any attempts to preserve where these famous people might have lived. Granted, I imagine it would look like like rubble at this point, if much of anything at all, but it piqued my interest.

I couldn't find that information on Google.

Comment: What does it mean "Aristotle's slight dark age of having his materials burned" ?

Comment: See [Greek Architecture : Housing](https://www.ancient.eu/Greek_Architecture/).